# USB to ethernet chips like LAN7850 require GPIO to RESET pin?

Tags: ethernet, reset

I am designing a PCB which uses [LAN7850](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/LAN7850) chip

This is the first time I'm using such a chip and I'm very newbie to PCB designing.

Please advise if this Chip requires a GPIO pin from the microcontroller to control the RESET_N as I have done in this image.

[image: RESET]

Design Rule Checks:

[image]

Comment: what's that mosfet doing in the reset signal line? why?

Comment: It's a good idea to have the reset line tied with a "board level" reset otherwise you won't be able to reset the chip without a board power cycle. Also because of timing requirements, you may have to reset this chip after the MCU/MPU starts up, or hold it in reset until a power rail comes up. Are you using this chip in USB mode, or HSIC?

Comment: Mosfet simulates a button press so I'm using it to remove the issue of interference and the influence of levels. Ron - I am using it in USB mode. So it is always the best option to connect a GPIO?

Comment: Also, it is recommended to use 4 layers for ethernet but I am able to fit my components in 2 layers with all the rule checks. Do I proceed with this 2 layers?

Comment: Yes, I would have it. You should also have a 4 layer board, with the two inner layers being ground and power. This is important. You also need to pay attention to USB and RX/TX pair differentials/matched lengths and they really need to be routed above a reference plane.

Comment: I have posted my design rule checks. Can you please check and comment? The PCB price difference will be huge if I use 4 layers

Comment: DRC isn't going to catch you not using a reference plane, follow guidelines here or your board may be worthless. A couple extra bucks upfront is better than getting boards that don't work. 4 layer boards aren't that expensive compared to 2 layer, when you move to 6+ layers is where the price really jumps.

Comment: @Arahasya if you want help with PCB design it would be best to start a new question with a picture of the board layout. All your DRC shows is that components and traces don’t violate constraints like size and clearance.

Comment: okay thanks for the inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't necessary as USB has a provision built into the protocol for the host to initiate a reset. This is how it would be used if, for example, the device were a USB-to-LAN dongle.

However, you *should* have a reset to the IC that is held down until after the LAN7850 power becomes stable.

As a nice-to-have, OR-ing the power-on reset with a GPIO reset might be useful for testing or for power management.

Comment: thanks for your inputs